# MVVM. When I change the value of a property of my model, it is not displayed in the view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am creating a WPF application. This application contains a model, a view and a viewmodel that are the following.
Model:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public PersonModel(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class PersonViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly PersonModel _person;

    public PersonViewModel(PersonModel person)
    {
        _person = person;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => _person.Name;
        set
        {
            _person.Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get => _person.Age;
        set
        {
            _person.Age = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<Window x:Class="testMvvM.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testMvvM"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Height="50"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Age}" Height="50"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

CODE BEHIND

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private PersonModel person = new PersonModel("Hola", 12);
    private PersonViewModel personViewModel;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        personViewModel = new PersonViewModel(person);
        DataContext = personViewModel;
        _ = ChangePersonAsync();
    }

    private async Task ChangePersonAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        person.Age = 30;
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        personViewModel.Age = 50;
    }
}
```

I would like to ensure that changing the value of the name or age property in the model propagates the change to the View.
If I change the property in the ViewModel, the change does propagate to the model and the View, but if I change them in the model, the get call of the ViewModel does not come and it does not come displayed in the View
sorry for my English

Comment: Your model doesn't notify the view model or the view about any changes.

Comment: What is the best way to make the model notify the view model?

Comment: Raise an event like you are doing in the view model. But why do you need this when you have a view model? Can't you simply set the wrapper properties of the view model instead of interacting directly with the model?

Comment: I'm new to mvvm and I thought that the view model is in charge of notifying the view when a property of the model is changed and when a value changes in the view that needs to be updated in the model.

Comment: I imagine it in the following way. If I had a service that retrieves my name and age from a database, I have to update the model which then triggers the notifications viewmodel --> view. But if after I retrieve the data from the database I change the ViewModel as you suggest, the structure would be model <-- viewmodel --> view, this does not go against the principle of MVVM? And the most interesting question is this strategy that I am doing to wrap the properties of the model in the viewmodel, is it correct? thank you for responding so quickly mm8

Comment: The service is part of the model. The view model may change the model and then also notify the view of the change.